# How can I dynamic set a value into a property?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

How to set a property to value that should be resolve.. like this one..

```
const getDataFromServer = (id) => ({id: * 2})
R.set(payloadProp, getDataFromServer)({id: 4}); // WRONG, is setting to a function instend to resolve a function with `{id: 4}`
```

---

```js
const fetch = (id) => {
  return { num: id * 2 }
};

const idProp = R.lensProp('id');
const getDataFromServer = R.pipe(R.view(idProp), fetch);

const payloadProp = R.lensProp('payload');
const setPayloadFromFetch = R.set(payloadProp, getDataFromServer); // NOT WORK, return payload as function

const obj = { id: 1, payload: { message: 'request' } }
const ret = setPayloadFromFetch(obj);
console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`R.set`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#set) takes a value, not a function, for its second parameter.  And you can't switch to [`R.over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over), which does take function but calls it with the current value at that lens, not the full data object supplied to the outer function.

The simplest way to solve this is simply to pass the object in both places:

```
const setPayloadFromFetch = obj => R.set(payloadProp, getDataFromServer(obj), obj);
```

But if you're intent on making this point-free, [`lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) is your friend:

```
const setPayloadFromFetch = R.lift(R.set(payloadProp))(getDataFromServer, identity);
```

although you could also use [`R.ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap), which would be very nice except that `R.set` takes its parameters in the wrong order for it, and so you have to use [`R.flip`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip)

```
const setPayloadFromFetch = R.ap(R.flip(R.set(payloadProp)), getDataFromServer);
```

You can see all these in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20fetch%20%3D%20%28id%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20num%3A%20id%20%2A%202%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20idProp%20%3D%20R.lensProp%28%27id%27%29%3B%0Aconst%20getDataFromServer%20%3D%20R.pipe%28R.view%28idProp%29%2C%20fetch%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20payloadProp%20%3D%20R.lensProp%28%27payload%27%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20setPayloadFromFetch%20%3D%20obj%20%3D%3E%20R.set%28payloadProp%2C%20getDataFromServer%28obj%29%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20or%0A%2F%2F%20const%20setPayloadFromFetch%20%3D%20R.lift%28R.set%28payloadProp%29%29%28getDataFromServer%2C%20identity%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20or%0A%2F%2F%20const%20setPayloadFromFetch%20%3D%20R.ap%28R.flip%28R.set%28payloadProp%29%29%2C%20getDataFromServer%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20payload%3A%20%7B%20message%3A%20%27request%27%20%7D%20%7D%0AsetPayloadFromFetch%28obj%29%3B%0A)**.